# Как нарисовать три кружочка на css?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Нужно создать три кружочка как на фото
Если сделать с помощью after и before я так понимаю получиться только два элемента ?
[image: макет]

Comment: это может быть один элемент с тремя точками(просто символы - точки), с примерно `color: orange` и возможно с `text-shadow`. незачем там целых три элемента лепить

Comment: @puffleeck Спасибо)

Comment: Теперь в ответе 3 варианта с описанием, чем они отличаются.

Comment: Исправил ошибки и описания.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ниже приведены 3 варианта (`.a`, `.b` и `.c`) с градиентами. У них общая идея, но вот чем они отличаются между собой:

1. `.a` Responsive по вертикали, но предполагается, что `closest-side` достигается по вертикали. В принципе, с помощью математики можно просчитать и другие варианты.
2. `.b` Нельзя указать размер круга в процентах.
3. `.c` Responsive по горизонтали (можно сделать аналогично по вертикали или в обоих направлениях), но нужна поддержка браузером [container queries](https://caniuse.com/css-container-queries).

Пиксель добавляется для более хорошего сглаживания. Если есть необходимость работы в браузерах без поддержки [`calc`](https://caniuse.com/calc), то надо продублировать полностью свойство с фоном и у первого убрать calc, оставив число, совпадающее с предыдущим.

```css
div {
  width: 9em;
  height: 3em;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

div + div {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.a {
  background:
    radial-gradient(closest-side circle at 25%, blue 45%, transparent calc(45% + 1px)),
    radial-gradient(closest-side circle at 50%, blue 45%, transparent calc(45% + 1px)),
    radial-gradient(closest-side circle at 75%, blue 45%, transparent calc(45% + 1px));
}

.b {
  background:
    radial-gradient(.75em circle at 25%, blue 100%, transparent calc(100% + 1px)),
    radial-gradient(.75em circle at 50%, blue 100%, transparent calc(100% + 1px)),
    radial-gradient(.75em circle at 75%, blue 100%, transparent calc(100% + 1px));
}

.c {
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.c::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;

  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at 25%, blue 8cqi, transparent calc(8cqi + 1px)),
    radial-gradient(circle at 50%, blue 8cqi, transparent calc(8cqi + 1px)),
    radial-gradient(circle at 75%, blue 8cqi, transparent calc(8cqi + 1px));
}
```

```html
<div class=a></div>
<div class=b></div>
<div class=c></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать с помощью теней. Там удобнее получаются степени двойки, но можно обрезать размером контейнера. Накладывать одну точку на другую для скрытия совмещением в теории возможно, но фактически будут артефакты сглаживания, поэтому не рекомендую.

```css
div {
  width: 6em;
  height: 3em;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  position: relative;
}

div + div {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

div::before {
  content: "";

  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 auto 0 .5em;
  margin: auto;

  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  filter: drop-shadow(2em 0 0 blue) drop-shadow(4em 0 0 blue);
}

.x {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class=x></div>
```